# What was the causeway span leading to the Bifrost Bridge made out of?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

In the movie 'Thor', the causeway to Bifrost was obviously a power-feed to the bridge. It looks like a deck comprised entirely of some kind of hybrid crystalline and fiber optics power-feed cables routed from the Asgard city grid to the bridge controls. Would this be an accurate assessment and have their been any commentaries about it's composition or construction?

[image: https://www.fxguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/MAN-FX-0181.jpg]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [original Norse poems](http://mythology.wikia.com/wiki/Bifr%C3%B6st) (on which much of the "mythos" in the films Thor and its sequel are based), the bridge is described as being made of the colours of the rainbow;

> *"Hana muntu sét hafa, kann vera at þat kallir þú regnboga. Hon er með þrim litum ok mjök sterk ok ger með list ok kunnáttu meiri en aðrar
>   smíðir"*
>
> (*"Thou must have seen it; it may be that ye call it 'rainbow.' **It
>   is of three colors,** and very strong, and **made with cunning and
>   with more magic art** than other works of craftsmanship."*)

I remain unconvinced that this will help with the film adaptation where, as you say the Bridge seems to be composed of glass and electronics.

Comment: Fiberoptic (light) conduits. Those old Norse poems were sure prescient... or were they just talking about what they saw?

Comment: Actually I think the actual 'bridge' would more accurately be the beam/transporter/wormhole/Einstein–Rosen bridge that Heimdall activates. The colored causeway is what feeds 'power?' to the mechanism that activates the bridge (between worlds). Still, your answer is a good step forward.